# Parse text files Java

Tags: java, io, text-files

I  need to write a java program that can take in either a path to a file or directory of files.  Go through the files, and parse the  text file into smaller files and put them in a folder.

For example the file name "abc"

It should output a folder called xyz that contains abc files.

abc1.y
abc2.y.

any help is appreciated

Comment: Always search for an already-existing answer online before posting your own question. Just google the problem and you should find more than you need. Unless you cannot get an existing program to work or have a question about specific behavior, please refrain from posting questions on how to do something this trivial.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably hw so I am just going to give you a good starting point. First you should look into the **File** class and you are most likely going to want to use the **getName**() method. Then store all the file names into an array and sort. Or you can sort them as you are putting them into an array